# Do I always need to validate request variables

Tags: php

Do I always need to validate user input, even if I'm not actually saving them to a db, file, or using them to include files etc..

Say I just wanted to echo out a request variable or I was using it to send email, is there any need to validate or sanitise it? I've always heard people say that all user input should be checked before doing anything with it, but does it actually pose any threat, if I'm not doing any of the above?

Comment: What if the request variable contains `<script>alert('haxxor');</script>`? What would happen if you "just echo out" it?

Comment: Even if you're "just" echoing it out. How would you feel if I echoed out an iFrame?

Comment: It's not just about you and your db ...

Comment: But you'd be the only person to see the iframe or alert box. I'm not saving the data anywhere.

Comment: "I've always heard people say that all user input should be checked before doing anything with it" actually this is wrong. What you are trying to do / prevent is based on the context it is going to be used in. So you only need to try to prevent stuff when actually using it somewhere. And to answer your question: yes of course you need to prevent xss.

Comment: @user1380500 but it allows me to run malicious code that does all kinds of nasty stuff, no matter who sees it

Comment: @PeeHaa, how will anyone else see it, if its only rendered on your own browser?

Comment: Who said the issue is anybody else seeing it? I could download a malicious payload, steal you cookies, change your page, insert malicious thing here.

Comment: If it's a request variable, it means that someone else could create a link to it from somewhere else. Or trick the user to do it themselves.

Comment: How is it possible to run malicious code unless I'm using my variable with eval or something? Do you have any references?

Comment: @user1380500 Look up XSS. Example: you echo $_GET['search'] in a search result page. Normally this shows up as Search: "search term here". If a malicous user then sends a link to friends with yoursite.com/?search=<script src="evil.site/evil.js">, then it will execute the js which could steal the users cookies, forge your login page to send the users credentials to the malicous user, add an iframe with a virus installer, etc etc.

Comment: Erm, YES. If you’re “just” echo-ing a request variable, someone can add an XSS (cross-site scripting) attack on your site. If you’re passing request variables to an email script, then it can be used to inject malicious commands. Don’t be stupid. There’s a reason people say _never_ trust user input; they didn’t make it up for the sake of it.

Comment: Not really a programming issue; just a “Why should I do X?” question.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend it.
my rule is - NEVER TRUST USER'S INPUT. 
lets say that your'e working on a team.
as you wrote, you build a simple form that submit the data to php file and than mail it.
after 3 weeks another team mate wants to use that form.
he's assuming that the data in the php file is clean . he dont know that you dont filtered it.
this is a crack for troubles.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I always need to validate user input, even if I'm not actually saving them to a db, file, or using them to include files etc..

Everything you are going to do with user supplied data depends on the context in which you are going to use it. In your single sentence you are already talking about 3 different contexts (db, file, include). Which all will need a different strategy to prevent things for that specific context.

> Say I just wanted to echo out a request variable or I was using it to send email, is there any need to validate or sanitise it?

There are more things you can do besides validating and sanitizing. And yes you should handle this case (which is another context btw). Basically you should handle *all* user data as if it is malicious. Even if you are "just `echo`ing it". There are numerous things I could do when you are "just `echo`ing".

Considering we are in the context of a HTML page I could for example (but not limited to) do:

```
<script>location.href='http://example.com/my-malicious-page'</script>
```

Which can be for example an exact copy of you website with a login form.

```
<script>var cookies = document.cookie; // send cookieinfo to my domain</script>
```

Which can be used to get all your cookies for the current domain (possibly including your session cookie). (Note that this can and imho should be mitigated by setting the http only flag on the cookies).

```
<script>document.querySelector('body')[0].appendChild('my maliscious payload containing all kinds of nasty stuff');</script>
```

Which makes it possible to sideload a virus or something else nasty.

```
<!--
```

Fuck up your layout / website. There are several ways to do this.

> I've always heard people say that all user input should be checked before doing anything with it

This is mostly wrong. You only need to decide how you are going to handle a piece of data once you know what you are going to do with it. This is because you want to prevent different things in different situations. Some examples are (but not limited to): directory traversal, code injection, sql injection, xss, csrf.

All above attack vectors need different strategies to prevent them.

> but does it actually pose any threat, if I'm not doing any of the above

yes totally as explained above. All data that is coming from a 3rd pary (this means user input as well as external services as well as data coming out of the database) should be treated as an infectious disease.